# Can't convert Hash to JSON before :show action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I try to convert Hash to JSON before viewing it on page, but can`t convert type of variable. Example in console (rails c):

```
2.1.5 :001 > @item = Item.find(2)
  Item Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "items".* FROM "items"  WHERE "items"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 2]]
 => #<Item id: 2, nested_params: {"123"=>"123", "456"=>"456"}> 
2.1.5 :003 > @item.nested_params.class
 => Hash 
2.1.5 :004 > @item.nested_params = @item.nested_params.to_json
 => "{\"123\":\"123\",\"456\":\"456\"}" 
2.1.5 :005 > @item.nested_params.class
 => Hash 
2.1.5 :006 > @item.nested_params
 => {}
```

Comment: Do you have `serialize :nested_params, Hash` in your `Item` class?

Comment: I understand that the variable is not overridden. JSON has type String by default

Comment: Without knowing what `nested_params` is in the data model it's difficult to help.

Comment: No, if you have serialized the attribute then you can not save or edit that attribute to have some other format than the defined one. Rails resets its value every time you touch the serialize attribute. You need to show your `Item`(item.rb) code.

Comment: Thanks to User089247, this work! I just add `serialize` to model and converting success. Make answer pls, i will vote

Answer (score 2):

You can visit below link 
http://www.rexfeng.com/blog/2012/12/convert-a-ruby-hash-into-valid-json/

I think you have to write require 'json'